# python webdriver find element by xpath by class within a span with text

Tags: python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have used Python 2.7, Webdriver and Chrome to access Pinterest to insert images to a board. I have successfully logged in to the site and created a board. The problem that I have is when my code attempts to click the add pin element, I get an exception.

The element is the "+" button at the bottom right of the page (see attached "red arrow"). I have attached an image of the Chrome inspect on the element.

I have seen one answer in my research which suggests that Webdriver with Chrome has a problem with "span" in some cases. Please note that I can click the element manually anywhere in the button.

My code:----

```
print "e20 addbutton"

addbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='accessibilityText' and contains(text(), 'Save Pin')] ")

print addbutton
if addbutton.is_enabled():
    print "addbutton enabled"
    if addbutton.is_displayed():
        print "addbutton displayed"
        addbutton.click()
```

The output from the above is:----

> e20 addbutton
>
> addbutton enabled
>   addbutton displayed

I get the following exception for the addbutton.click():----

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>
> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable
>   at point (871, 845). Other element would receive the click:  
>   (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.25.426923
>   (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.14393 x86_64)

Comment: I cannot see my attachments, adding them separately.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the `<span>` tag, which you've correctly located by XPath, I'm not sure clicking it will do anything. Have you tried obtaining the XPath to the `<button>` instead?

Try out this code instead:

```
addbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@data-element-type="18"]')
# --- #
if addbutton.is_displayed():
    print "addbutton displayed"
    addbutton.click()
```

This worked for me.

Comment: //button[@data-element-type="18" worked, thanks. I could not find any example of this on any Q and A forum.